# iPhone/Objective-C UIActionSheet with programmatically added buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet, ibaction

I have a `UIActionSheet` that contains buttons that are programmatically added depending on whether a property contains a value or not.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonTap:(id)sender {
    MyObject *obj = (MyObject *)[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage];

    if (obj != nil) {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Details"
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

        // Programatically add Other button titles if they exist.
        if (obj.firstProperty) {
            [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Dosomething"];
        }

        if (obj.secondProperty) {
            [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Dosomethingelse"];
        }

        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Static button"];

        actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

        [actionSheet showInView:self.view.window];
        [actionSheet release];
    }
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    MyObject *obj = (MyObject *)[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage];

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0: // Dosomething
            break;
        case 1: // Dosomethingelse
            break;
        case 2: // Static button
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is, how do I account for the fact that one of the properties may be null and handle that within the `clickedButtonAtIndex:`? The index values will change. I have around 4 or 5 different buttons, each displayed depending on whether a property contains a value of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use the `buttonTitleAtIndex:` method of `UIActionSheet` to get the button title and use this to determine what action to take.

Alternatively you could use logic similar to where you add the buttons to figure out exactly what the index means.

Comment: Fixed by using: NSString *buttonString = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]; thanks a million.